# vslam does not publish visual odometry data

Tags: ros, visual-odometry, vslam-system, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The vslam seems to work fine for stereo stream but The topic /vo is advertised but it is not published , and i can see no output when i do :
rostopic echo /vo

So what might be wrong ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10542/vslam-does-not-publish-visual-odometry-data-./) by [rajat](https://answers.ros.org/users/591/rajat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 175 on 2011-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/1914/vslam-running-on-your-own-data) for initial setup, synchronization, etc. Then modify line 159 of vslam_system/src/nodes/stereo_vslam_node.cpp to have if(1). After that there are three crucial steps:

1. Create a URDF for your robot that has a base_link. It is useful to have a camera_base link somehow connected to base_link for later steps.
2. You will have to have a node that broadcasts a transform from base_link to odom. See [REP 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) for more information about the map -> odom -> base_link transforms. This node also needs to listen for the transform between base_link and visual_odom. Note that visual_odom is the frame_id and base_link is the child_frame_id in vslam_system/src/nodes/stereo_vslam_node.cpp.
3. When starting your camera nodes they must both have frame_id set to camera_base if that is what you have in your URDF. If your URDF only has a base_link then you can set the frame_id to base_link.

When you have your robot model loaded in Rviz along with the nodes to (i) run your cameras and (ii) publish the transform between base_link and visual_odom, then you should see point clouds and camera poses appear in Rviz. I have [not](http://answers.ros.org/question/1408/vslam-node-crashes-after-some-time) seen it work well [either](http://answers.ros.org/question/574/what-techniques-might-improve-vslam-performance).

Also, [this ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4753) has a patch that I recommend applying to fix a big memory leak.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2011-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did the following:

in the file vslam_system/src/nodes/stereo_vslam_node.cpp

go to line 159 and replace "if (0)" by "if (1)"

(then do a rosmake vslam_system)

---

Originally posted by [philippp625](https://answers.ros.org/users/227/philippp625/) with karma: 21 on 2011-07-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1